# Exim listed in htop, but not installed - server sending spam

Tags: spam, ubuntu-12.04, exim

So, I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server on Amazon. It recently started sending spam emails. When I do htop to see the proceess list, I can see the exim process there, but it's NOT installed! We're using postfix.

[Htop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLs9L.png)

What I tried so far:

- kill the process (reappears immediately)
- upgrade everything (apt-get update && apt-get upgrade)
- Enable X-PHP-Originating-Script in my logs (But it doesn't show in the logs)
- ps aux: `www-data 22612  0.4  0.1  35660  7152 ?        Ss   09:24   0:01 exim`
- netstat -lp 
  `Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
  tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN      28881/master

  tcp        0      0 *:27450                 *:*                     LISTEN      5731/exim`

Any help appreciated...I tried searching but found nothing.

Comment: Here's what I have for iptables:

`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination         

DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:27450 state ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination         

DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27450 state NEW,ESTABLISHED`

Comment: As a side note, I will re-deploy my websites on a new server, as this one's likely compromised.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To start, you can block exim using iptables to prevent spam from being sent as you investigate the issue.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5731 -j DROP
```

(This assumes that you are running iptables on the VM for your firewall. If not, you should check into blocking the traffic through whatever firewall you're running).

For general security install rootkithunter, configure and run a scan. You may find that your VM has been compromised.

Here is a guide for compiling from source since the packaged versions are out of date:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rkhunter-to-guard-against-rootkits-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: rkhunter found nothing. I used your suggestion and so far, it looks like it's working. I think the problem was with an out of date WP install. Will keep that in mind. Solution in my original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

exim is running as www-data which should not normally be the case. Your server has probably been compromised by some malware.

You can have some more info on the exim process by looking at /proc//exe which is a symlink to the actual binary. You may also use ps axjf to get its parent process.

I would suggest you to restore your server from the last safe backup.

Comment: That was my worry...the process links back to /usr/bin/perl

Answer (score 1):

You can fidn path of the current executable, look at `/proc/<PID>/exe`, which is a symlink to it.

```
ls -l /proc/<PID> | grep exe
```

But as your server has been compromised - it is better to re-deploy it from scratch.

Comment: It links to the perl executable...
`ls -l /proc/20098 | grep exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 0 Dec  7 10:09 exe -> /usr/bin/perl`

Comment: @Robert Run ` cat /proc/<this proc id>/cmdline`  to view which script is executed in perl. And recheck process id - it could be already changed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have already killed the process and used IPTABLES to block the offending port. So far it seems like its working.
I'll keep your comment in mind should the problem resurface.

Comment: Don't wait when problem resurface - re-deploy or at least cleanup you server! If the vulnerability remains - it will soon take advantage of again.

Comment: I will re-deploy on a new VM. Just needed to clear this one for now as I only have time to do it this week-end.